# (MYSQL) I keep getting ERROR 2013- Lost Connection during query

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, database-connection

We run a data centric web server using CentOS 6.4 and MySQL 5.1.69. We recently migrated to a new server with more RAM(32GB). We weren't having this issue before, but we copied the the my.cnf from the old server so that can't be the case. The OS (CentOS 5.7) and MYSQL version were older (don't know the specifics for MySQL as it completely crashed).

ANYWAY we migrated and everything is working fine on the client side. The problem arose (or at least we became aware of it) when we tried to create and populate a new table. Here's a little context:

- We have a table, gauge_data (~39,551,658 rows, 8.3 GB of space), that contains raw data.
- When a user wants to view this data, we do calculations on this data in real time every time. Super inefficient so its really slow and the users have been complaining.
- This new table (processed_gauge_data) is meant to hold the calculated data so the calculations only need to be done once
- We created a Symfony(v1.4) Task to pull the data from gauge_data, do the calculations, and then insert the calculated data into our new table. This Task also makes sure there are no duplicate entries by looking at the timestamps.

So we got the task working and attempted to insert the past years worth of gauge_data into our new table. Seemed to work fine, but took a few days. But now when we try run the Task it will timeout in the middle of the query (ERROR 2013), maybe a minute or so after we start it. It was at this point I noticed that the same would sometimes happen in phpMyAdmin or MySQL for certain queries. There were even some queries where it worked one time and then timeout out another. Trying to run CHECK TABLE processed_gauge_data; returns 
"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query" between 15-45 seconds. For reference, processed_gauge_data currently contains ~11,321,913 rows and is using 2.3 GB of space. ALSO mysqldump fails which has been messing up our backup Task. There is nothing in the error log.

Here is the my.cnf for reference:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
connect_timeout=30
net_read_timeout=600
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/lib/mysql-slow.log
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql


# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1


# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# This is my configuration!
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON
innodb_flush_method: DIRECT_IO
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_log_buffer_size=12M
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow switching from mysql to mysqli got everything working. Can anyone shed some light on this?